# Calculating the volume of an Elliptical tank, where the top and bottom ellipse are different sizes

Tags: geometry, volume

I need to calculate the volume of an Elliptical tank/tube, where the top and bottom ellipses are different sizes. I have done some research and have only really found formulas for calculating an Elliptical tank where the top and bottom are equal. Any help would be appreciated, if the answer could be posted in a way thats easy for me to read as im not too math savvy with all the symbols etc (i understand pi, pow etc...)

This is the kind of object im trying to calculate the volume from
[Elliptical Tank](http://www.onlineconversion.com/images/object_volume_elliptical_tank.png) but where the two ellipises are different sizes

This is the [geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbY7Z.png) that im trying to calculate the volume of

Comment: You need to specify how the sides of the tank are formed. Do the axes vary in length constantly? Are cross-sections of the tank also ellipses, or is the tank shaped like the convex hull of the top and bottom faces? Is the tank a truncated cone?

Comment: For example, if it's a convex hull, suppose you have a $1000$ by $1$ ellipse on the top face and a $1$ by $1000$ ellipse on the bottom face. The convex hull of these faces will be very close to a tetrahedron, and cross-sections of a tetrahedron are definitely not ellipses.

Comment: By the "sides" do you mean the top and bottom sections of the object? Imagine the elliptical tank as a cylinder basically, but replace the circly bits with ellipses

Comment: By the sides I mean the bits of surface that aren't the top and bottom faces, because there are several different possible ways to define them, and they result in different volumes.

Comment: Of course the calculation will be more simple if your ellipses are homothetic, because then what you get is a truncated cone.

Comment: Just updated the answer of a fairly crudely drawn shape of what im trying to calculate. But that is just an example, the radius/size of the top and bottom shapes could change to be bigger or smaller

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlmZu.png) the kind of hull you're looking for, or should it be shaped differently given the top and bottom sides?

Comment: No, did you see my edit? i posed this image as an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbY7Z.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the volume of an elliptical truncated cone? if so

[image][image]

See this link: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/15374075528834

Comment: That is exactly what i mean! And the calculation seems super easy. Have some fake internet points

Answer (score 0):

We have that the surface area for an ellipse is give by $S=\pi ab$ therefore if we know how $a$ and $b$ are vary along the axis $z$ we have

$$V=\int_0^H S(z)dz=\pi \int_0^H a(z)\;b(z)\; dz$$

Comment: Can you explain this a little further? I dont know much about maths and providing values like S, z dz etc arnt too much help for me. Because what are those values? Like i said im not math savvy, i need to broken down a little more

Comment: @JakeWade The volume depends upon how the shape changes along the height. In general we need integration to calculate it. If you are interested in some specific solution we can determine it.

Comment: i have updated my question with a image of the geometry that im trying to calculate the volume of